# Encrypted backup to Google drive

Tags: backup, encryption, google, google-drive

I have a computer that is having serious issues, and I don't know how long it will last.  I would like to backup my home directory, and upload it to the cloud like my Google drive, how would I do that?

Comment: Since most ISP's have a slower upload rate (than download rate), doing backups this way would take forever, and could be unreliable. And how much do you trust Google with your data? Best to purchase an external USB drive and backup files to that.

Comment: Just need to do it once

Comment: Once is all it takes to get a good backup, so you can have a good restore. I stand by my suggestion.

Comment: You should be able to use the built in backup tool (deja dup) to create a backup, and then upload that to a google drive folder. However, as @heynnema says, it would probably be a lot easier and certainly safer and faster to use an external drive, especially given the low prices of flash memory.

Comment: clear your cache and trash first. `rm -rf ~/.cache`. Then use tar https://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-home-directory/

Answer (score 1):

As @heynnema stated in comments, the best way to do this is probably with a portable hard drive. That being said, I'll give you a couple of options, starting with doing it your way.

---

**Encrypting and Backing up to Google Drive *(NOT RECOMMENDED)***
*Warning:* This is going to require that you have enough free space on your disk to duplicated your the contents of your home directory in compressed format

While logged in as the user whose directory you want to backup, open a terminal and preform the following actions:

- Change to your home directory
  `cd ~/`
- Compress the contents of your home directory to an encrypted, compressed file which will be saved in `/home`. When prompted for a password, use something secure as it will be used to encrypt the compressed backup. Just to be on the safe side, we'll split this up into 1G files as well. I don't know what kind of limit Google puts on the file size.
  `sudo tar -cJf - ~/ | gpg2 -c | sudo split -b 1G - ../$USER-home.tar.xz.gpg.`
- At this point, you should have a bunch of files named similarly in `/home` all named like `YOUR-USERNAME-home.tar.xz.gpg.*`. If your home directory is a gig or less, there will only be one file. Check to see by running:
  `ls /home`
- You can upload each of these files to your Google Drive, assuming you have enough space available to you, and all of the contents will be encrypted!

When you want to pull them back down off of Google drive, save them all to a single directory. Change to that directory in a terminal and run one of the following commands, changing `YOUR-USERNAME` to the username reflected in the backup files. When a password is requested for decryption, enter the same password that you used to encrypt the backup:

- Decrypt to compressed tar file:
  `cat YOUR-USERNAME-home.tar.gpg.* | gpg -d > /path/to/save/tar/file/YOUR-USERNAME-home.tar.xz`
- Decrypt and decompress right to `/home/YOUR-USERNAME`:
  `cat YOUR-USERNAME-home.tar.gpg.* | gpg -d | tar -xJf -`

---

**Backing up to an external hard drive *(RECOMMENDED)***
Plug in your external drive and run the following command from a terminal:

- Create an uncompressed, unencrypted backup to your hard drive with permissions preserved regardless of the file system on the hard drive.
  `sudo tar -cf /path/to/your/hd/$USER-home.tar ~/`

When you're ready to access the backed up files, you can simply open the tar file from the hard drive and copy anything over or extract the entire thing.

Comment: Cloud gdrive gives you off-site backup. Take your USB work flash backup home and your Home backup to work and stick it in your desk drawer.